# Python won't import function

Tags: python, python-import

I have a simple `time.py` file:

```
import datetime
import time
import re
def cnvrt1(time):
    hr = int(re.split(":",time)[0])
    min = int(re.split(":",time)[1])
    sec = int(re.split(" ",re.split(':',time)[2])[0])
    ampm = re.split(" ",re.split(':',time)[2])[1][0]
    zone = re.split(" ",re.split(':',time)[2])[2][0]
    if ampm == 'P' && hr < 12 :
        hr = hr + 12
    elif ampm == 'A' && hr == 12 :
        hr = hr - 12;
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(year=2013,month=10,day=22,hour=hr,minute=min,second=sec)
    res1 = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
    if zone =='M':
        res1 = res1 -  3600000;
    if zone =='C' :
            res1 = res1 - 3600000*2;
    if zone == 'E' :
           res1 = res1 - 3600000*3;
    return res1
```

However when I say `from time import cnvrt1`, it says `ImportError: can't import name 'cnvrt1'`. Can anyone point me to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You are using the wrong name. There is *already* a module named `time` in the standard library, and that module is probably already imported by other code you are using. You are even using `import time` in the code you posted here, which would otherwise create a circular import.

The best option is to rename this module to something else.

If you are using Python 3, and placed `time.py` inside a package, you can qualify the import to be within the current package:

```
from .time import cnvrt1
```

Note the `.`. This would allow you to retain the current name; Python 3 switched to using absolute imports by default and a `time` module inside a package won't conflict with the global `time` module.

You are also using invalid Python syntax in your module. Python uses `and`, not `&&` for boolean logic:

```
if ampm == 'P' && hr < 12 :
```

should be

```
if ampm == 'P' and hr < 12:
```